# iOS 8 UILabel text is null issue

Tags: ios, ios8, uilabel

I have an issue in the iOS 8 with the `UILabel`. I am printing a text on the view while the text won't remove from the view if the result1 is bigger than the result2 while it is working fine in the iOS 7. And I have debugged and found that the `label1.text` is always null before I remove it from the screen. Please where would be my issue?

```
-(void)warningAlert{

    label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 85, 300, 660)];

    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    label1.numberOfLines=0;

    [self.view addSubview:label1];

        if (result1 < result2)
    {
        if (printed == NO) {

            label1.text = @"“Warning Warning!!”";

            printed = YES;
        }

    }
        else{

        NSLog(@"check the value %@", label1.text);

        [label1 removeFromSuperview];
        printed = NO;
    }
```

Comment: How did you create the UILabel object? Is it a label on your storyboard/xib? - Though it looks like if your code goes into the else part of the method, then you've not actually set any text to the UILabel, in which case null is exactly what it'll say

Comment: If you call your method more then once with result1 < result 2, you will always create a new label and draw it on the view. Only if result 1 >= result 2 you will remove the last created label immediatly. That whole method makes absolutly no sense.

Comment: Opss I didn't mention that. Thanks @ClausBönnhoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding and removing the label.

1. Alloc the memory to label only once in viewDidlload
2. And then Just hide or unhide the label.